# dompdf can't print the desired result

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, dompdf

Im trying to generate report but all im getting is this:
[The PDF output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZz29.png) I wanted to print out date from my database but instead im only getting this one word. I think it has to do with php error but im not able to find my mistake. im new to this, i hope u guys can help me out. thanks.

My model:

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class GeneratePdfController extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('model_user');
        $this->load->library('pdf');
        $post_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $x['data'] = $this->model_user->get_user_by_nip($post_id);
        $html = $this->load->view('GeneratePdfView', $x, [], true);
        $this->pdf->createPDF($html, 'mypdf', false);
    }
    
}
?>
```

My View file

```html
<?php
$b = $data->row_array();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Create PDF from View in CodeIgniter Example</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <h1 class="text-center bg-info">Generate PDF from View using DomPDF</h1>
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Nama</th>
                <th>Nip Baru</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><?php echo $b['n']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $b['nipBaru']; ?></td>
            </tr>

        <tbody>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where you initializes $html variable ? `$this->pdf->createPDF($html, 'mypdf', false);`

Comment: $html = $this->load->view('GeneratePdfView', $x, [], true);

Comment: And function index()?

Comment: in the controller which should be called when user click generate report

Comment: Cast `$html` to a string? `$this->pdf->createPDF($html.'', 'mypdf', false);`